# Simple Dynamic Web Scraping - Without BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, dynamic, web, screen-scraping

I'm busy trying to scrape a dynamic website in order to get a URL that I can use to download the server software for a game every time it updates.

The site is "http://craftstud.io/builds" and where it says "Server XX.X.X.X" is what I'm trying to scrape.

I really don't want it to get complicated with Javascript and external modules, so if there is a simple solution I am all ears.

I also can't for the life of me get third party modules installed such as BeautifulSoup (Stupid Windows).

Thanks all!

Comment: I believe it's sometimes there is a legitimate reason not to install 3rd party modules; in your case you could learn how to use easy_install or pip in windows.  This can be done quite easily with some googling, and you won't be limited to the standard library anymore

Comment: What's wrong with Windows? You can install any modules with pip/easy_install or just put in your project's directory.

Comment: Parsing html with standard library is much more complicated, than installing a third party module. Try to do it, and if you get stuck, come back and ask for help.

Comment: @dm03514 - Yes there is a legitimate reason. I'm busy programming on Windows for Linux and I might end up distributing the script across multiple Linux VPS'. So I don't want to end up troubleshooting all the servers trying to find missing modules all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something simple, consider using a simple [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> import urllib2
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen("http://craftstud.io/builds").read()
>>> re.search(r"Server \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", html).group()
'Server 0.1.24.1'
```

That said, if you can install [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download) via pip, you'll find lots of use for it in the future. (Make sure you use `pip install BeautifulSoup4` instead of just `pip install BeautifulSoup` I just installed a copy on a windows machine a couple days ago.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the example. However I didn't use the exact same method. I ended up replacing re.search with the string plus ".*\" which means any character, * means repeating continuously and then \ means stop repeating when you find the text after that. Thanks though!